# Video upload from wordpress frontend

Tags: uploads

Can I upload a video from a wordpress frontend which can be approved by admin in adminpanel? I want a video gallery which is uploaded by frontend user and display in same page.

Comment: Hi, askign support related questions for third part plugins are considered [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your best bet is to contact the plugin developer directly on their support form.

Comment: Do you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, users can upload videos, try this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/